# Finding the Time and distance of the closest point for two linear parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this specific example,  there are two ships moving straight represented by the parametric equations $\left(\frac{474t}{120} ,\frac{-735t}{120} +735\right)$ and $\left(\frac{-255t}{120} +255,\frac{954t}{120}\right)$.

What I am trying to get is at what time will the distance between both ships be the shortest, what that distance is, and what the positions of the ship are when the distance is the shortest.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint - Minimize the function
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{729t}{120} -255\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{1689t}{120} +735\right)^{2}
\end{equation*}
Get the value of t which minimizes this function, find the value of the function and then get the coordinates of the point at this moment of time t.

Comment: I don't know how to minimize functions, I tried to use the internet to minimize the function but it seems that the time that I get is way off from the closest point just by looking from the eye. Is this the only way to solve this question?